# Circunference arch movement with M. Zelle's Graphics

Tags: python, graphics, angle

I came up with this idea for describing an arch and I don't understand why it doesnt work for every initial angle.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKaSR.png)

```
for i in self.obstaculos:
        dist = sqrt(((self.getX()-i.getX())**2)+(self.getY()-i.getY())**2)
        print(dist)
        if (dist <=15):
            theta = atan((i.getY()-self.getY())/(i.getX()-self.getX()))
            gama = pi - 2*((theta-self.alfa))
            alfa_i = (3/2)*pi + theta
            alfa_f = alfa_i + gama
            while alfa_i < alfa_f:
                dx = cos(alfa_i+0.05)*1.5
                dy = sin(alfa_i+0.05)*1.5
                for el in self.conjunto:    
                    el.move(dx, dy)
                alfa_i += 0.1
                update(60)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you have on image. You could use `print()` to see values in variable in different moments - and compare it with your calculations on paper. And sometimes problem can be because usually computer use `angles` in `radians` and we expect `degrees`

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run. In current version it is hard to say what is wrong.